# Does Bootstrap 3 require jQuery to make the repsonsive menu work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am not really familiar with Bootstrap but I looked to find out if I could use the responsive menu without jQuery.  I can't find anything in the documentation and would appreciate if someone could give me some advice on this.

Comment: What value is there in not using jQuery?  It's ubiquitous now.

Comment: My manager has mentioned a solution that does not use jQuery.

Comment: That's not what I asked: why?  What on earth is accomplished by setting such a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The responsive menu uses the toggle functionality in Bootstrap and all of Bootstrap's Javascript depends on jQuery.

You might be able to find implementations which dont depend on jQuery though.

Edit:  a quick google search yielded quite a few pages mentioning this, here's one for example: https://mpetroff.net/2015/03/bootstrap-navbar-without-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm pretty certain it does for the animations and responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does but there are libraries created that don't rely on it, like this:

[Bootstrap javascript with no jQuery required](https://github.com/tagawa/bootstrap-without-jquery)